# open sets of suspension

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am reasoning on a problem. I have a topological space $X$ and I consider its suspension, namely $SX= X \times [0,1] / \{X \times \{0\}, X \times \{1\} \}$
the suspension $SX$ is covered by the two cone $C_0 X, C_1 X$, are these set open in $SX$? do they form an admissible cover for $SX$ ?

Comment: It depends how you define $C_0 X$, $C_1 X$. They can be open, if they overlap a bit, or if $C_0 X$ is $SX$ without the "north pole". Can you write your definition of admissible cover please?

Comment: yes an admissible cover for a topological space $X$ is a couple $ \{U,V \}$ of subset of $X$ such that $X=interior(U) \cup interior(V)$